# Display feedback within modalwindow before close

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, wicket, wicket-7

Given the following structure within a `ModalWindow` I like to make use of the forms toastfeedback panel to display feedback messages before closing the ModalWindow, so i don't have to delegate them to a parent container:

```
ModalWindow
└─ Content
   └─ Form
      ├─ ToastFeedback (*)
      └─ AjaxSubmit
```

(* display feedback with JavaScript as toast message. Rendered toasts will stay, even when the ModalWindow is removed from DOM)

I'm trying to implement a function to queue another ajax request right after the current has finished. So the new request is a new round trip.

```
new AjaxButton("submit") {
    public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        // do the form processing
        form.success("all good");
        target.add(form);

        queueAnotherAjaxRoundTrip();
    }
};
```

Any ideas are pretty welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `target.appendJavaScript("makeAnotherAjaxCall()")`.

`makeAnotherAjaxCall` may use `jQuery.ajax()` or `Wicket.Ajax.xyz()` with or without wrapping the call in `setTimeout()` depending on your needs.

If you use `Wicket.Ajax` APIs then there is no need of `setTimeout` if you use the same `AjaxChannel`. If you do not know what is `AjaxChannel` then you use the default one and your extra Ajax call will be just queued, as you want.